# When using a subcomponent in a databinding layout, how to get the subcomponent to compile correctly?

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

I have a java databinding layout that I'm using inside another java databinding layout. The subcomponent renders correctly when viewed alone, but when I look in the design view for the supercomponent it does not render the subcomponent, and has null reference error in the design view errors panel under "Failed to instantiate one or more classes". It compiles and runs as expected. Looking inside the autogenerated BindingImpl file, the reference for any views that use databinding are not being generated, hence the reference error. How can I get the subcomponent to instantiate correctly?

If I remove all of the databinding from the xml and put into code, the component displays correctly in the design view (but defeats half the purpose of using it). Project compiles correctly with no errors, although design view says there are, in addition to the "Failed to instantiate..." error

[Autogenerated] ComponentNumberPickerBindingImpl.java

```
static {
        sIncludes = null;
        sViewsWithIds = new android.util.SparseIntArray();
        sViewsWithIds.put(R.id.number_picker_minus_button, 2);
        sViewsWithIds.put(R.id.number_picker_plus_button, 3);
    }

private ComponentNumberPickerBindingImpl(androidx.databinding.DataBindingComponent bindingComponent, View root, Object[] bindings) {
        super(bindingComponent, root, 1
            , (android.widget.ImageButton) bindings[2]
            , (android.widget.ImageButton) bindings[3]
            , (android.widget.TextView) bindings[1]
            );
        this.mboundView0 = (android.widget.LinearLayout) bindings[0];
        this.mboundView0.setTag(null);
        this.numberPickerText.setTag(null); // java.lang.NullPointerException error here
        setRootTag(root);
        // listeners
        invalidateAll();
    }
```

component_number_picker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
    <data>

        <variable
            name="numberPicker"
            type="shared.NumberPicker" />

        <variable
            name="target"
            type="androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData&lt;Integer>" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/number_picker_minus_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/border_circular"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc_remove_large_luggage_button"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_remove_24px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/number_picker_text"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="60dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            tools:text="9"
            android:text="@{`` + target}"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/number_picker_plus_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/border_circular"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc_add_large_luggage_button"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_24px" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

NumberPicker.java

```
package shared;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;

import databinding.ComponentNumberPickerBinding;

public class NumberPicker extends LinearLayout {

    ComponentNumberPickerBinding mBinding;

    public NumberPicker(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initialiseViews(context);
    }

    public NumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialiseViews(context);
    }

    public NumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initialiseViews(context);
    }

    private void initialiseViews(Context context) {
        mBinding = ComponentNumberPickerBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true);
        mBinding.setNumberPicker(this);
    }

    public MutableLiveData<Integer> getTarget() {
        return mBinding.getTarget();
    }

    public void setTarget(MutableLiveData<Integer> value) {
        mBinding.setTarget(value);
    }

}
```

Include

```
<shared.NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/luggage_specifier_number_picker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I believe that this is a bug in the data binding code when used in the design view. I traced the app code while it was running, and noticed that it was assigning a tag (I couldn't see where this happens, presumably somewhere in the DataBinding setup) to each of the views in the subcomponent, which are used by the ViewDataBinding class to assign to the view properties in the binding implementation.

However, these tags do not appear to get set when using the design view, so the views never get added to the view bindings array, and thus never get assigned to the view properties.

I found a workaround for this, which is to manually assign the tags (these are e.g. binding_1, binding_2 etc.). When the code builds, it finds the tags and assigns them correctly, and the view renders as expected.

*UPDATE*
After a bit more digging, it seems like the binding tag is in there, but it doesn't get picked up for some reason - these two layouts are from the auto generated component_number_picker.xml
Note that the TextView has an "originalTag" attribute, where as the ImageView does not. In this example, I added a tag in the layout xml to the TextView, but not the ImageView. When viewed in design view, the TextView instantiates correctly, but the ImageView causes a NullReferenceError.

```
<Target id="@+id/number_picker_text" originalTag="binding_2" tag="binding_2"
            view="TextView">
            <Expressions>
                <Expression attribute="android:text" text="`` + target">
                    <Location endLine="50" endOffset="40" startLine="50" startOffset="12" />
                    <TwoWay>false</TwoWay>
                    <ValueLocation endLine="50" endOffset="38" startLine="50" startOffset="28" />
                </Expression>
            </Expressions>
            <location endLine="51" endOffset="36" startLine="40" startOffset="8" />
        </Target>
        <Target id="@+id/number_picker_plus_button" tag="binding_3" view="ImageButton">
            <Expressions>
                <Expression attribute="android:onClick" text="()-&gt;numberPicker.increment(1)">
                    <Location endLine="61" endOffset="61" startLine="61" startOffset="12" />
                    <TwoWay>false</TwoWay>
                    <ValueLocation endLine="61" endOffset="59" startLine="61" startOffset="31" />
                </Expression>
            </Expressions>
            <location endLine="61" endOffset="63" startLine="53" startOffset="8" />
        </Target>
```